# Finding $\nabla^2V $ if $V=\frac{2\cos\theta+3\sin^3\theta \cos\phi}{r^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

How do you find $\nabla^2V $ if $V=\frac{2\cos\theta+3\sin^3\theta \cos\phi}{r^2}$

The correct answer is supposedly $\frac{6\sin\theta \cos\phi(4-5\sin^2\theta)}{r^4}$, but I can't seem to get the answer. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where exactly do you get stuck?

Comment: [Del in spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Three_dimensions).

Comment: @Sobi Thanks for offering to help. This was where I got to: https://imgur.com/tDpPjxQ. Unfortunately, I can't get it to simplify. I'm not sure if I did a wrong step.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplacian in spherical coordinates is given by: 
$$
\nabla^2{V}=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}} \left(r^2 \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} \right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin{\theta}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}} \left(\sin{\theta} \frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta} \right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2{\theta}}\frac{\partial^2{V}}{\partial{\phi^2}} = 0$$

Proceeding carefully, the **first term** gives:
$$ \begin {align}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial{r}} &=\frac{-4\cos\theta-6\sin^3\theta\cos\phi}{r^3} \\
{r^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial{r}} &= \frac{-4\cos\theta-6\sin^3\theta\cos\phi}{r} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}} \left({r^2}\frac{\partial V}{\partial{r}}\right) &= \frac{4\cos\theta + 6\sin^3\theta\cos\phi}{r} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}} \left(r^2 \frac{\partial V}{\partial r} \right) &= \frac{4\cos\theta + 6\sin^3\theta\cos\phi}{r^4}
\end{align}  \nonumber $$

The **second term** gives:
$$ \begin {align}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial{\theta}} &=\frac{-2\sin\theta + 9\sin^2\theta\cos\theta\cos\phi}{r^2} \\
\sin\theta\frac{\partial V}{\partial{\theta}} &=\frac{-2\sin^2\theta + 9\sin^3\theta\cos\theta\cos\phi}{r^2} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\left(  \sin\theta\frac{\partial V}{\partial{\theta}} \right) &= \frac{-4\sin\theta\cos\theta + 9\cos\phi \left(3\sin^2\theta - 4\sin^4\theta\right)}{r^2} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{r^2 \sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial{\theta}}\left(  \sin\theta\frac{\partial V}{\partial{\theta}} \right) &= \frac{-4\cos\theta + 9\cos\phi \left(3\sin\theta - 4\sin^3\theta\right)}{r^4}
\end{align}  \nonumber $$

The **third term** gives:
$$ \begin {align}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial{\phi}} &= -\frac{3\sin^3\theta}{r^2}\sin\phi \\
\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial{\phi}^2} &= -\frac{3\sin^3\theta}{r^2}\cos\phi \\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2\theta} \left(\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial{\phi}^2} \right) &= -\frac{3\sin\theta\cos\phi}{r^4} \\
\end{align}  \nonumber  $$

Adding up all three terms gives:
$$ \begin {align}
\nabla^2{V} &= \frac{4\cos\theta + 6\sin^3\theta\cos\phi - 4\cos\theta + 9\cos\phi \left(3\sin\theta - 4\sin^3\theta  \right)  -3\sin\theta\cos\phi   }{r^4} \\
&= \frac{6\sin^3\theta\cos\phi + 27\sin\theta\cos\phi -36\sin^3\theta\cos\phi -3\sin\theta\cos\phi  }{r^4} \\
&= \frac{24\sin\theta\cos\phi -30\sin^3\theta\cos\phi }{r^4} \\
&= \frac{6\sin\theta\cos\phi \left(4 -5\sin^2\theta \right)}{r^4} \\
\Rightarrow \nabla^2{V} &= \frac{6\sin\theta\cos\phi \left(4 -5\sin^2\theta\right)}{r^4} 
\end{align}  \nonumber $$